# Groovy eclipse compile fails to compile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a spring boot based groovy micro service I cloned from Github. I opened the project in Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition (2017.3.5) Build #IU.173.4674.33.

The Project loads fine but when I run:

`mvn clean package -DskipTests` 
or 
`mvn clean package` 
or 
`mvn clean install` 
or
`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

It fails to compile.

This is the mvn build log:

```
[ERROR] /dev/projects/non-core-apis/core-payload-commons         /src/main/groovy/com/payload/commons/request/MassPaymentHelper.groovy:  [141,2] 505. ERROR in /dev/projects/non-core-apis/core-payload-commons/src/main/groovy/com/payload/commons/request/MassPaymentHelper.groovy (at line 141)
[ERROR]         @Override
[ERROR]

      ^^^^^^^^
```

Now override is just one of the complained classes, it can not resolve Date class as well.

This is the stacktrace when i enable stacktrace logging for mvn:

```
mvn clean package -skipTests -e


org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project switch-payload-commons: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have switched to Eclipse compiler on intellij same error.

This is maven dependency build setup:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

I have struggled with this since yesterday any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It will be easier if you provide a link to the github repository

Comment: @borino it's a private repository, I would have added it if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved!!!

Apparently, I have both Java 8 and Java 9 installed, even when I switch to Java 8 in intellij I still could not compile. I just uninstalled java 9 and left only java 8.

Compiled and booom no errors.

After this nightmare I guess I will have to set up another dev environment if I want to play around with Java 9.

Thaanks guys!